# Regex: negative lookbehind AND negative lookahead

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to match the word `gay` unless it is part of the word `megayacht`. I know I can use negative lookahead and negative lookbehind to exclude `gayacht` or `megay` from the match, e.g

```
(?<!me)gay
```

and

```
gay(?!acht)
```

but using

```
(?<!me)gay(?!acht)
```

will still exclude `megay` and `gayacht` from the match, which is not what I want. I can't find a way to require both simultaneously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```js
gay(?!(?<=megay)acht)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/XRIxXN/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  gay                      'gay'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      megay                    'megay'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    acht                     'acht'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Answer (score 3):

You could exclude matching `megayacht` and match the word containing `gay`

```
\b(?!megayacht\b)\w*gay\w*
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fPqF34/1)

Comment: I've noticed that the first `\b` must be *outside* of the lookbehind but can't figure out why. Can you tell me why?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann The word boundary should be placed outside of the lookahead because the pattern should assert from the current location where the word boundary matches, that what is directly to the right is not the word. If you place it inside the lookahead the logic is different. It starts with the assertion stating: if from the current position are word boundary followed by the word is not directly to the right. That assertion is true at the position before `egayacht`

Answer (score 3):

You can use an alternation pattern:

```
(?<!me)gay|gay(?!acht)
```